# Projection of a set of 4D points to the 3D space

Tags: graphics3d, linear-algebra, vector-calculus

Consider the following set of points in the 4D space:

```
points = {{Log[5], Log[2], Log[8/5], Log[23/16]}, {Log[5], Log[2], Log[23/17], 
  Log[17/10]}, {Log[5], Log[16/11], Log[11/5], Log[23/16]}, {Log[5], 
  Log[17/12], Log[23/17], Log[12/5]}, {Log[5], Log[23/18], Log[11/5], 
  Log[18/11]}, {Log[5], Log[23/18], Log[3/2], Log[12/5]}, {Log[5/3], 
  Log[6], Log[8/5], Log[23/16]}, {Log[5/3], Log[6], Log[23/17], 
  Log[17/10]}, {Log[11/7], Log[16/11], Log[7], Log[23/16]}, {Log[3/2],
  Log[17/12], Log[23/17], Log[8]}, {Log[11/7], Log[23/18], Log[7], 
  Log[18/11]}, {Log[3/2], Log[23/18], Log[3/2], Log[8]}, {Log[4/3], 
  Log[6], Log[2], Log[23/16]}, {Log[17/13], Log[6], Log[23/17], 
  Log[13/6]}, {Log[4/3], Log[12/7], Log[7], Log[23/16]}, {Log[17/13], 
  Log[13/8], Log[23/17], Log[8]}, {Log[9/7], Log[23/18], Log[7], 
  Log[2]}, {Log[9/7], Log[23/18], Log[7/4], Log[8]}, {Log[23/19], 
  Log[6], Log[2], Log[19/12]}, {Log[23/19], Log[6], Log[19/13], 
  Log[13/6]}, {Log[23/19], Log[12/7], Log[7], 
  Log[19/12]}, {Log[23/19], Log[13/8], Log[19/13], 
  Log[8]}, {Log[23/19], Log[19/14], Log[7], Log[2]}, {Log[23/19], 
  Log[19/14], Log[7/4], Log[8]}}
```

All the points lie on a 3D hyperplane since `MatrixRank[# - points[[1]] & /@ points]` returns 3. How can I show the points in a 3D space (e.g., using `Graphics3D`) so that the distance of points are kept intact?

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D`?

Comment: You should project the points into 3d first.

Comment: When you say that you want the distance of the points to be left intact, do you mean the distance as measured on the hypersurface, or that in the 4d space. You can look at points on a sphere and their 2d and 3d distance will be very different.

Comment: I mean "the distance as measured on the hypersurface".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

I got a `MatrixRank` of 4 with the original approximate data, but with the updated exact data, the rank is 3.

The basic idea is that `Orthogonalize` will return an orthonormal basis for the subspace spanned by the vectors, along with some zero vectors interspersed.  (Orthonormal means unit length vectors that are pairwise perpendicular.)  Deleting the zero vectors leaves the basis in the form of a matrix -- in other words, they form a 3D coordinate system in the hyperplane with the origin at the first point.  Multiplying the 4D vectors by the matrix yields the 3D coordinates of the subspace.

**With the exact coordinates**

The following shows the result:

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Darker@Red,
  Point[
   With[{vectors = # - First@points & /@ points}, 
    N @ DeleteCases[Orthogonalize[vectors], {0, 0, 0, 0}].Transpose[
       vectors] // Transpose]
   ]
  }]
```

[image: Projected points]

**With the approximate coordinates**

Replace the `{0, 0, 0, 0}` with `{0., 0., 0., 0}` in `DeleteCases`.  For example,

```
With[{vectors = # - First@points & /@ N@points}, 
 DeleteCases[Orthogonalize[vectors], {0., 0., 0., 0.}].Transpose[vectors] // Transpose]
```

The original question had numbers with only six digits of accuracy.  In that case one needed

```
Orthogonalize[vectors, Tolerance -> 10^-5]
```

and the results were correspondingly accurate (5 decimal places).

Comment: Thanks Michael for your rapid answer. I know pretty much nothing about linear algebra. I get 4 for `MatrixRank[points]`but 3 for `MatrixRank[# - First@points & /@ points]`. What does it mean? Doesn't it imply that they lie on a 3D hyperplane?

Comment: Your result implies that the points lie on a 3D hyperplane, but my result of 4 for `MatrixRank[# - First@points & /@ points]` implies they do not.  Is there an error in the points posted in the question?

Comment: Rounding errors, I guess. I get the same result as yours when I copy the points from the webpage. Could you please explain a bit about the mathematical details of how your code works.

Comment: I updated the point set. It should be ok now.

Comment: @Mohsen Yes, the points are ok now.  I added some details.  I wasn't sure how much additional explanation you needed.

Comment: One can also get the coordinates this way: `vectors.Transpose@N@DeleteCases[Orthogonalize[vectors], {0, 0, 0, 0}]`